# How to solve the app crashes in doing navigation view on both side in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-navigationview

I have referred to this blog [tutorial](https://v4all123.blogspot.com/2016/03/simple-example-of-navigation-view-on.html). But, I cant figure out, where did they get "R.menu.main" in this coding?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and.. where did they get "R.id.action_settings" ?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I tried to change my coding by adding a little bit based on this blog tutorial. My apps still crash, it suddenly close.

Comment: Those methods have nothing to do with the dual `NavigationView`s, and were likely leftover from a basic project template, so you can just delete them. If you still have a crash, then you'll need to look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause.

Comment: Thank you sir. I already figure it out. Error at my toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that it asks you for an xml file where the menu elements are supposed to be, what you should do is create a folder called **"menu"** in your **"res"** directory as seen in the image and then in **"menu"** "create the resource **"main.xml"**.

[image]

already in your **"main.xml"** file, you should find the id of the elements...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/home_item" />
   <item
      android:id="@+id/about_option"
      android:title="@string/option_item" />
   <item
      android:id="@+id/suggestions_nav"
      android:title="@string/suggestions" />
</menu>
```

I hope I've helped! :D

Comment: I already have the menu and all the item where I name it as activity_home_drawer and activity_home_drawer2. Should I make main.xml in the menu folder?

Comment: If you tell me that your menu is called "activity_home_drawer" then what you would have to do is replace in the line of code as follows:
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_drawer , menu);

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it sounds like you may be missing a `menu.xml` resource file. Try adding one to your project.

[Android Development - getMenuInflater(R.menu.main, menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514540/android-development-getmenuinflaterr-menu-main-menu)

Comment: yes sir, i didnt put the this coding getMenuInflater(R.menu.main, menu. because I cant figure out where did it get the menu.main... (?)